# Firefox is not triggering paste event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating application in which I need to bind `paste` and other events to handle data in a textarea.

I have 15 rows and 65 cols in my textarea.

I have created [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/o2tmm469/).

To produce problem try to follow following steps:

1. In first line enter fill it with full 63 characters.
2. In second line enter only few characters.
3. Now in both line try to press ctrl + v.

In first line console will display only one message. (`KeyDown` event)

In second line console will display two message. (`KeyDown` and `paste` event)

```
$('#myTextArea').on('keypress', function(event) {
    console.log('not working');
});

$('#myTextArea').on('paste', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Event Fired... Hurray");
});
```

Please let me know is there any simple way to handle this paste event in all browser.

Comment: Firefox on Mac is in fact triggering the paste event.... but as an aside, what if the user uses the mouse to paste?

Comment: If there's anything in the fiddle that isn't in the question and is necessary to understand the question (like your whole "To produce the problem..."), it must be **in** the question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to handle the generic event, `input`, which is triggered regardless of how the field got data added to it:

```
$("#myTextArea").on("input", ...);
```